# Easiest online team collaboration tool

Tags: pm-software, software, team

I would need an online team collaboration (project management) tool very easy to use.

I don't need a lot of features, just these ones:

- assign tasks to team members
- comment on tasks
- give time estimation to tasks
- mark tasks as done
- categorise tasks by projects, releases, tags

What software would you recommend? An hosted solution would be ideal. We are a medium-size company.

Comment: There are several posts in the [pm-software](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pm-software) tag; could you edit your question to include more about what you have looked at that doesn't fit the bill?

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at that link.
To be honest, I haven't really tried any of them yet because I am overwhelmed with choices. I have just tried Podio (as everybody is talking about it) which is great but I was looking for something more streamlined.

Comment: TFS Service is free, and hosted online.

Comment: Can you clarify "medium-size company"?  How many development teams do you have?  Are your teams collaborating with each other, or working on independent projects without dependencies?  Finally, what does your process look like -- You want a tool that supports how you work.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend https://trello.com/

Have been using it for tracking activities of my team ( size - 10 testers)

It is straightforward, not too clutter or complexity , is free and should tick the boxes from your question

Comment: I do agree with you, but in my experience, Trello seems to be a little week regarding tagging/categorization. Do you have any special workaround on that?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind paying, then Flow is an excellent option: http://www.getflow.com/

You can assign/delegate tasks to team members, comment on tasks, mark them as done, and categorize using tags for your projects and releases.  It also has due dates, recurring tasks, a calendar view that you can subscribe to, and even attachments.

The only thing I don't see from your list is the ability to add estimates, although that could be easy enough using custom tags, a naming scheme, or just the description field.

It has a great iPhone app and simple little Mac app for quick entry and Growl notifications. as well.  Highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

We use [www.smartsheet.com](http://www.smartsheet.com).  The look and feel is similar to a spreadsheet, so it's quite easy to use without much training.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview) easy to use .. free to use up til 10 users .. and a lot of expansions if you need more sophisticated functions.

Comment: AFAIK, Jira most-basic version (up to 10 users) is $10,00/mo. Still, an amazing tool, but maybe a bazooka to kill this fly.

Comment: If you host the installation yourself it is only 10$ one-time payment, so you´re right it is not free. And you´re right that it is a large toolbox.. but it is easy to get started and you are ready for expanding, when you meet limitations.

Answer (score 0):

The new one, on the market is wunderkit. Its free but advanced features require you to pay. 
Here:
http://www.wunderkit.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try [clockingit](http://www.clockingit.com). It's free, has everything you need + more but it's still not complicated at all to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a look at [Workgroups](http://www.metacommunications.com/products/workgroups). I've used the hosted system for quite some time at my current job. We use it to manage job tickets, proofs, digital resources, time and expenses, etc. Worth a look if you want something a bit more customizable and powerful then some of the free solutions out there.

Answer (score 0):

[Disclaimer: I am the founder of the company behind Collaborade.com]

Hi.

We have recently launched [Collaborade.com](http://www.collaborade.com)

It is a very simple online software for team collaboration and we want to keep it simple.

We are planning to potentially add time estimates as a plugin in the future.

It is not free but we believe it is money well spent.

Answer (score 0):

The features you mentioned are quite common for most of the PM tools, so I suggest you go with the one you like the feel of. For instance, the tool we use, [Wrike](http://www.wrike.com), addresses all the points from your list:

- We can **assign tasks both from the system and via e-mail**. BTW, this
  e-mail integration has been a real time-saver for our team.
- We can **leave comments both from the task panel and from the live Activity
  Stream**, and even quote the comments left by the other team members.
- Yes. And besides **scheduling the tasks**, we also can “backlog” them,
  which is pretty convenient for keeping track of ideas and “someday”
  tasks. And the Gantt chart helps us get a clear picture of the
  overall project.
- Yes, also **both from the system and via e-mail**.
- Yes, we can even **color-code** them.